# How to handle - Application has stopped working in Android

Tags: android, error-handling, logcat

So I am trying to create an Android app which basically reads out the twitter feed according to the search query inside a UI. The feed that I need to display form the parsed JSON is the user name, handle, profile picture and the tweet.

Now I have created the whole thing and my code compiles but as soon as I run it the app opens and I write something in the search feed and hit enter - " Unfortunately, AppName has stopped working " I am attaching my logcat and my source code for reference.

*Solved the issue by removing set text from DoInBackground and then giving adequate permission for Android to access internet. The issue now is that as I try and display the profile picture, the URL gets displayed, not the image.

Source code :

```
package com.example.twittersearchactivity;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TwitterSearchActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tweetDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_search);
        tweetDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tweet_txt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.twitter_search, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void searchTwitter(View view){
    EditText searchTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_edit);
    String searchTerm = searchTxt.getText().toString();
    if(searchTerm.length()>0){
        try{
            String encodedSearch = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "UTF-8");
            String searchURL = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+encodedSearch;
            new GetTweets().execute(searchURL);
            Log.i("1", "entered the searchterm");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
        tweetDisplay.setText("Enter a search query!");
    }
    private class GetTweets extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... twitterURL) {
            StringBuilder tweetFeedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String searchURL : twitterURL) {
                HttpClient tweetClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    HttpGet tweetGet = new HttpGet(searchURL);
                    HttpResponse tweetResponse = tweetClient.execute(tweetGet);
                    StatusLine searchStatus = tweetResponse.getStatusLine();

                    if (searchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        HttpEntity tweetEntity = tweetResponse.getEntity();
                        Log.i("2", "entered gettweets");
                        InputStream tweetContent = tweetEntity.getContent();
                        InputStreamReader tweetInput = new InputStreamReader(tweetContent);
                        BufferedReader tweetReader = new BufferedReader(tweetInput);
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = tweetReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            tweetFeedBuilder.append(lineIn);
                            Log.i("3", "entered while in dobackground");
                        }
                    }
                    else {Log.i("error", "error");}
                        //tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
                    //tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}

            return tweetFeedBuilder.toString();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            StringBuilder y;
            StringBuilder tweetResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Log.i("tag", "entered try block");
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray tweetArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int t=0; t<tweetArray.length(); t++) {
                    Log.i("tag", "entered the json stream");
                    JSONObject tweetObject = tweetArray.getJSONObject(t);
                    tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.getString("from_user")+": ");
                    tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.getString("from_user_name")+": ");
                    tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.get("text")+"\n\n");
                    String imageURL = (String) tweetObject.get(("profile_image_url")+": ");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    d.setAlpha(255);
                    TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,1,0);
                   }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                tweetDisplay.setText("Whoops - something went wrong!");
                e.printStackTrace();}

            if(tweetResultBuilder.length()>0)
                tweetDisplay.setText(tweetResultBuilder.toString());
            else
                tweetDisplay.setText("Sorry - no tweets found for your search!");
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call view functions like `setText` on another thread like an `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` function.  You need to do it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Did that, commented both the setText in AsyncTask doInBackground but now on searching a query it just diplays " sorry, no tweets found" even though a similar query in the web browser displays results.

Comment: Sounds like a separate problem.  I'd run it under a debugger and see what's going wrong where.

Comment: Solved that issue by giving permission for android to access the internet in the manifest but am not able to display the jpeg image now, it just displays the url.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the bitmap you created, at least in the above code.